# How to perform Multiple Linear Regression in R where Number of Independent Variables is Greater than Cases?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

I have a dataset with 75 independent variables and only 30 cases/ samples. function `lm` isn't working as  there are limits, such as when you have more predictors than cases you run into issues in parameter estimation. So, how can I perform Multiple Linear Regression here. Is there any way available?

Comment: number of solutions is likely to be infinite

Answer (score 3):

You can't do ordinary linear regression.  There may be several sets of coefficients which may explain the data equally well.  Consequently, the choice of coefficients is underdetermined.

You could try a penalized regression method, like elastic net (for which the more popular LASSO and ridge regression are special cases).  If inference is your goal (e.g. confidence intervals and unbiased estimation), you lose this when doing penalized inference.

Comment: Bootstrap and track how many times each parameter is nonzero for lasso inference?

Comment: What if I use any feature selection method and multicollinearity test so that I can reduce the number of independent variable?

Comment: @FazlaRabbiMashrur Feature selection a la something like stepwise is not a good idea, especially if you want to do inference.

Comment: @Dave What would that tell us?  Even if that could tell us what variables were important, what inferences could we make?  Inference with LASSO is a big interest of mine, and so if you have references that study the properties of this technique, share em.  I'd love to read them.  Which reminds me, I think [Ryan Tibshirani and coauthors recently did some work in post selection inference](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1521252212).

Comment: I read a post on here today about doing inference with lasso regression via bootstrap. Something makes me think it was your post.

Comment: @Dave Might have been.  My thoughts on the lasso and inference have changed, especially as I've read more on modelling.  I'll add that Frank Harrell's `rms` package does something similar for stepwise regression.  I'm not opposed to people using the bootstrap on the lasso, I just think we need to be more specific on what we would learn and what inferences are possible.  That's all

Comment: @DemetriPananos feature selection like RFE, NCA,  ILFS , InfFS, ECFS, mrmr, relieff .... how about that?

Comment: @FazlaRabbiMashrur  I am very doubtful that feature selection will help you in this case, primarily because you have so many features from which to select.  My advice here is to try penalized regression.